# Could Holy Prophet (PBUH) talk to animals and understand what they said?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

I just saw a page sharing a conversation between Holy Prophet (PBUH) and a an insect. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he did have the capacity to interact with animals. it is mentioned in exegesis that a camel complained to him for not being sufficiently fed upon which he instructed the owner to address the issue. Although there are not many instances quoted in the case of Prophet Mohammad, but it can safely be assumed that Prophets, as per the demand of the occasion, may elicit this endowed capacity by virtue of being special and chosen ones. This deduction/assumption is supported by the instance of Prophet Ibrahim ushering the desiccated birds from the hilltops to himself.